# Add formatting to downloaded file in tabulator

Tags: tabulator

When we download table data from tabulator in xlsx format, can we add formatting to that downloaded file?
Currently what we can do, we can send formatted data to download function...I want some formatting in downloaded xlsx file like wrap text,etc
If anyone knows anything about it please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment this isn't possible unless you create your own [custom downloader](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/modules#module-download)

This will be coming in a future release of Tabulator

*(i'm the founder of Tabulator, which is where this info comes from)*